# convertion method from vb.net to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

can we convert desktop application in vb.net to Asp.net

Answer (score 4):

If you mean some kind of autommatic conversion, then no you can't, You can port it certainly. If the application is already well written and loosely coupled, it may not be to difficult.